# Issue with return Value when calling stored procedure from EF4

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have written the following stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 :

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[usp_TodayNumberOfRegisteration] 
(
@TodayShamsiDate nvarchar
)
AS
Select COUNT(csci.Id) as cc1  FROM dbo.Complex_Service_Cart_Items csci INNER JOIN dbo.Complex_Service_Cart csc
ON csci.Id_Complex_Service_Cart=csc.Id
WHERE (csci.Id_Complex_Service='2cca1a67-34f4-4837-bebe-f3ba4c72b98d' or csci.Id_Complex_Service='8430cad2-dbb1-4425-bb8b-a7e158f688c4') 
and csc.TFIsPaymentComplete=1 
and csc.TFDateBackFromBankp= RTRIM( @TodayShamsiDate)
```

And I am calling it from C# codebehind via EF4 this way :

```
string shamsiDate = Date.getShamsiDate();
returnValue = Convert.ToString(db.getTodayNumberOfRegisteration(shamsiDate).First().Value);
```

where `getTodayNumberOfRegisteration` is a function I added to my `edmx` model .

Now here is the issue : when I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server and instead of

```
 and csc.TFDateBackFromBankp= RTRIM( @TodayShamsiDate)
```

I set something like :

```
 and csc.TFDateBackFromBankp= RTRIM( '1391/12/05')
```

This stored procedure returns a value of 6

But when I pass the parameter from C# codebehind and I get the return value '0'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue : 
I had set the parameter this way :

```
@TodayShamsiDate nvarchar
```

and I should have specified the length of nvarchar

```
@TodayShamsiDate nvarchar(10)
```

I did It and the problem is solved !

Comment: +1 ah yeah - missed that. If you don't specify a length, you'll get **1 character** length - and that's probably not what you wanted...

Answer (score 1):

I normally do it like this: in the `Add Function Import` dialog, select your stored procedure and define that it returns a *Collection Of Scalars: Int32*:

[image]

Then in your code, call it like this:

```
int value = db.getTodayNumberOfRegisteration(shamsiDate).First().Value;
```

This usually works just fine for me.

If you don't define it as *returns a collection of: Int32*, it seems that the value you're getting back is really the **return value** from the stored procedure call, e.g. the number of rows that were affected by the stored procedure execution (0 or -1 for a `SELECT`, since you didn't actually insert, update or delete any rows):

Comment: I have done the same thing , But I have no idea why It does not work !